# Flutter : path-related methods not work on iOS simulator inside a macOS VM

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios-build

I'm using OSX-KVM to run a macOS VM on Fedora, and run an iPhone 14 Pro Max simulator inside it.

Error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      PathProviderApi.getDirectoryPath (package:path_provider_foundation/messages.g.dart:40:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:121:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AppDir.setDir (package:flutter_wpp/entity/app_dir.dart:10:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      invokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/sqflite_impl.dart:16:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:7:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.getDatabasesPath (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:177:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      DatabaseFactoryExtension.getDatabasePath (package:floor/src/sqflite_database_factory.dart:23:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _$WppDbBuilder.build (package:flutter_wpp/db/wpp_db.g.dart:45:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      DbManager.setDb (package:flutter_wpp/db/db_manager.dart:8:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

the `flutter_wpp/db/wpp_db.g.dart` is generated by floor and works fine on Android.

Here is `flutter_wpp/db/db_manager.dart`:

```
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';

import 'wpp_db.dart';

class DbManager {
  static WppDb? database;

  static setDb() async {
    database = await $FloorWppDb
        .databaseBuilder('app_database.db')
        .addMigrations([]).build();
  }

  static WppDb get db => database!;
}
```

Here is `flutter_wpp/entity/app_dir.dart`:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class AppDir {
  static Directory data = Directory('');
  static Directory cache = Directory('');

  static setDir() async {
    data = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    cache = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  }
}
```

Both `getDatabasePath` and `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` are supposed to work on iOS. I have no idea why those errors happen.